# Cannot connect to database after AB testing

Tags: mysql

After testing the sites hosted on Digital Ocean using ab, MySql goes down and cannot connect to the database. It happens every time and I need to start the MySql service. Is there anyone what could be the reason and how to prevent this?

Comment: Did you try restarting the mysql service?

Comment: yes, restarting the mysql service works. but i don't understand why it goes down whenever i use AB with high number of connection (eg -n 1000 -c 5). even 1000 connections make the mysql go down.

Comment: Probably not enough memory, file handles or network sockets, since the max number of mysql connections is 2^32 = 4294967295